# svg circular animation with radius change

Tags: animation, svg

I have a circular animation for 10 secs on an svg circle.
The moment I try to change the `r="30"`on both the circles, the animation gets effected and last only for 5 secs. I think along with the `r` value I  would have to change the `cx` and `cy` values respectively to have a proper dimension and for animation to last for 10secs. Could you please point out what is going wrong?

Here's the link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxREMd

Here's the snippet:

```
<svg class="progress-circle definite" width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="transparent"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g transform="rotate(-90,50,50)">
    <circle class="bg" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" fill="url(#linear)"></circle>
    <circle class="progress" r="40" cx="50" cy="50" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: the circumference of a circle is dependent on its radius so the stroke lenght you need to cover it changes with the radius, hence so do the stroke-dasharray values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I surmise from your question that you must be reducing the circle radius. Am I correct?

If you reduce the circle radius the circumference of the circle reduces as well.  The "251" value, in the `stroke-dashoffset` property, corresponds to the circumference.

```
circumference = 2*PI*r = 2*PI*40 ~= 251
```

The animation works by shifting the position of a line dash pattern, so that it appears to slowly draw the line.

If you halve the radius, the circumference will halve as well.  If you don't also correct the `stroke-dashoffset`, the animation will appear to complete in half the time. That's because the animation has already reached the new circumference of 126 after 5 seconds.

To fix this, just update the `stroke-dashoffset` value to 126.

If you want to use a radius other than 20, you'll need to work out the correct circumference/`stroke-dashoffset` for that also.

```css
.progress-circle.definite .progress {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 126;
  animation: progress-anim 10s ease;
}

.progress-circle.definite .bg {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

@keyframes progress-anim {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 126; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}


// indefinite
```

```html
<svg class="progress-circle definite" width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="transparent"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g transform="rotate(-90,50,50)">
    <circle class="bg" r="20" cx="50" cy="50" fill="url(#linear)"></circle>
    <circle class="progress" r="20" cx="50" cy="50" fill="none"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation and solution. God bless!